# Is there a way to remove quotes from the output of a data frame entered into the toJSON function in R?

Tags: r, json, jsonlite, r-highcharter

I am trying to output a data frame in R as a json file to use for highcharts plots that I am making outside R. This is what my output looks like :-

```
[{"name":"alpha","value":1},{"name":"brave","value":2},{"name":"charlie","value":3}]
```

However, I want my output to look like this :-

```
[{name:"alpha",value:1},{name:"brave",value:2} {name:"charlie",value:3}]
```

What should I do so that the names of my data frame (in this case name and value) are not put into quotes? If converting my data into a json file is not the best way, what else can/should I do?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)
data = tibble(name = c("alpha", "bravo", "charlie"), 
              value = c(1, 2, 3))
output = toJSON(data, dataframe="rows")
write(output, "output.txt")
```

Comment: Your desired output isn't valid json, you realise?

Comment: Yes, you're right but I didn't know how else to phrase my sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way using `regex`, removing quotes from values appearing before colon `:`

```
json_string <- jsonlite::toJSON(data, dataframe="rows")

temp <- stringr::str_replace_all(json_string, '"(\\w+)"\\s*:', '\\1:')
cat(temp)
#[{name:"alpha",value:1},{name:"bravo",value:2},{name:"charlie",value:3}]

write(temp, "output.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to do this inside toJSON but you can use `mgsub` from the `qdap` library

```
sapply(names(data), function(name_i){
  output <<- mgsub(paste0("\"", name_i, "\""), name_i, output)})
```

That gives you

```
output
[{name:"alpha",value:1},{name:"bravo",value:2},{name:"charlie",value:3}]
```

Answer (score 0):

**An alternative way -**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)
data = tibble(name = c("alpha", "bravo", "charlie"), value = c(1, 2, 3))
output = toJSON(data)
output=gsub("\"(\\w*)\":", "\\1:", output,perl=TRUE)
print(output)
```

**Output -**

```
[{name:"alpha",value:1},{name:"bravo",value:2},{name:"charlie",value:3}]
```